# Entity Core Relationship With Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following base class (I am omitting constructors)

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int ClassAId {get;set;}
}
```

from which multiple classes derive. Among others, there are two classes that can hold a list of ClassB

```
    public class ClassA1:ClassA
    {
        public virtual List<ClassB> ClassBList {get;set;}
    }

    public class ClassA2:ClassA
    {
       public virtual List<ClassB> ClassBList {get;set;}
    }
    public class B
    {
       public int ClassBId{get;set;}
       public int ClassAId {get;set;}
       public ClassA ClassA {get;set;
    }
```

Please note that while it looks like I don't need to separate ClassA1 and ClassA2, there is a lot of other stuff going on that I am choosing to omit for simplicity.

I am now having trouble configuring the entity model. If I just had one ClassA that held a list of ClassB, I would do

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.ClassAId);

    entity.HasMany(a => a.ClassBList)
    .WithOne(b => b.ClassA)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClassAId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
}

modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.ClassBId);
}
```

But I could not get something similar to work for the case where I want ClassA1 and ClassA2 to be linked to ClassB. I tried using the HasMany/HasOne for both ClassA1 and ClassA2 using something like this (only showing ClassA1, I do the same for ClassA2)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA1>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasMany(a => a.ClassBList)
    .WithOne(b => (ClassA1)b.ClassA)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClassAId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
}
```

It creates the database, but throws a casting error when I try actually add a ClassB to ClassA1 or ClassA2. I am using Entity Core 2.0.

Comment: This not gonna work. Reference navigation property of type `ClassA` could have inverse collection navigation property defined only at `ClassA`. The relationship is always between **two** entities - `B` and `ClassA` in your case. It has nothing to do with inheritance. If you need separate `B` collections on `ClassA1` and `ClassA2`, then you need *separate* reference navigation properties (and FKs) on `B`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I will rewrite my classes to make this happen.